# How to check in Spock test that an exception in thrown in a Spring reactive class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-test

I am trying to test a service which should throw an exception if no result was found in the database. I am trying to test the case when there is no value found by throwing a NotFoundException. Here is the service. I want to test the condition when no result is found but the expected exception is not thrown in my test. I have included the test snippet.

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductService {
  private final ProductRepository ProductRepository;

  public Mono<Product> getProductById(Long Id){
    return ProductRepository.findProductById(Id)
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NotFoundException("No Product found")));
  }
}
```

Here is my test, irrelevant parts are omitted for brevity

```java
def 'A Product resource by product id which does not exist in db'() {

  given:
                    
  def id = 4444L

  productRepository.findProductById(id) >> Mono.empty()

  when: 'A call to get a Product is made to the service but cannot be found'

  def result = productService.getProductById(id)

  then: 'A NotFoundException is thrown from the service'
  
  // Does not work 
  StepVerifier.create(result).expectError(NotFoundException)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to use `verify()` in the end of your `StepVerifier` chain. We need to put `verify()` or other variations at the end of the chain. Otherwise, the `StepVerifier` won’t subscribe to our Publisher.

Here is a working example for your test-scenario:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class ProductTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class ProductTestConfiguration {

        @MockBean
        public ProductRepository productRepository;

        @Bean
        public ProductService productService() {
            return new ProductService(productRepository);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @Test
    public void when_not_found_ends_with_exception() {
        Long id = 4444L;
        // repository setup
        Mockito.when(productRepository.findProductById(id))
                .thenReturn(Mono.empty());
        // expect error, don't forget to call verify()
        StepVerifier.create(productService.getProductById(id))
                .expectError(NotFoundException.class)
                .verify();
    }
}
```

You can see the test passed:

[image]

---

If I change the repository setup with

```java
// return not empty, return new product
Mockito.when(productRepository.findProductById(id))
                .thenReturn(Mono.just(new Product()));
```

Then the test fails as expected:

[image]